Set position of multiple entities in UV Editor
So I ended up here:

In the UV Editor, I want all these little rectangles to be positioned the same X and Y value. The alt+Enter trick in the sidebar just places all the vertices into a point. I've also tried snapping and aligning but they don't seem to work in my case.

In edit mode, select all faces which correspond to the UV islands you want to edit, then press U > Reset.
In this way all faces will be overlapping and mapped on the entire UV Space.
Then in the UV editor, select all and resize as you need.

One option is to copy the uv coordinates of one of the uv islands and paste those same coordinates to all the other UV islands. The result is all islands stacked one above the other.
In the UV editor:

Select one of the UV islands,
Open the UV menu and select the Copy UV's option.
Invert the island selection using the Ctrl I shortcut.
With all the other islands now selected open the UV menu again and this time choose the Paste UV's option.

With all the islands stacked up you can move them to where ever you want in the UV space.

